# Cannot access variable, initialization not found

Tags: java

Program overview: Ask user for phrase, ask user for an index in which a scramble will rotate the phrase until that letter at index is the first index (0) of the string. Ask for an Integer until an integer is given. After phrase is scrambled ask to scramble again. if yes, scramble to inputted index, if no, print final result end program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PJ {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String phrase;
    String phraseMut;
    int index;

    System.out.println("Enter your word or phrase: ");
    phrase = scan.nextLine();
    phraseMut = phrase;
    System.out.println();

    while (true) {
      System.out.println("Enter the index of a character in your phrase: ");
      if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        index = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        break;
      } else if (index >= phraseMut.length()) {
        System.out.println("Error: Index is Double not Integer.");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Error: Index is not Integer.");
      }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Rotating phrase to bring index " + index + " to the front. . .");

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
      phraseMut = phraseMut.substring(1, phrase.length()) + "" + phraseMut.substring(0, 1);
      count++;
      System.out.println(phraseMut);
    }
  }
}
```

First for loop, I cannot access "index" as the compiler is stating it may not have been initialized. Any solution to access this?

Comment: The compiler is not able to infer the fact that within the `while`-loop, `index` must be set in order to exit the loop. Therefore, we have to initialize `index`. Easiest way is to initialize it at declaration: `int index = 0;`

Comment: @Turing85 The variable `index` is declared earlier in the method: `int index;`.

Comment: @BasilBourque declaration is not equal to initialization.

Comment: @Turing85 It is for a primitive.

Comment: No, it is only for fields, not for local variables. [Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/O2KEMS)

Comment: @Turing85 How did that fact escape me? Thanks for the correction. I posted an Answer to explain your point.

Comment: @BasilBourque happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Your line

```
else if (index >= phraseMut.length()) {
```

may be reading `index` before it's been set.  In particular, if the `Scanner` doesn't see an `int`.  You need to think about what value you want `index` to have, when that happens.  Like `0` maybe, or `-1`.

Then set `index` to that when you declare it.  So maybe you'd change `int index;` to `int index = 0;` for example, if that's what you decide you need `index` to be in the case where a value is not read from the `Scanner`.

Comment: When initializing an index variable like this, I typically set it to -1 so that it can't be mistaken for the first index in an array or string. In this case, if `phraseMut.length()` == 0 then there might be an error displayed when it's a false positive for that error.

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Kareem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69890930/642706) is correct.

To explain a bit more:

- **Member fields** of a primitive type such as `int` are automatically assigned a default value. The list of defaults is shown in the [*Primitive Data Types*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) tutorial by Oracle.
- **Local variables** of a primitive type such as `int` are *not* assigned a default value.

To quote the tutorial linked above:

> Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

For an example, see [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/O2KEMS), as posted by [Turing85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4216641/turing85).

```java
int i;
System.out.println(i);
```

> error: variable `i` might not have been initialized
> `System.out.println(i);`